# Connection string USING Application Intent errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, connection-string, high-availability

Trying to create a "read only" intent connection string against SQL Server 2012 high availability Group, following [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2869/configure-sql-server-2012-alwayson-availability-groups-readonly-routing-using-tsql/), I am getting:

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'application
>   intent'.    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey)

This is on a Windows 7 Pro machine, going against high availability group based on SQL Server 2012 (which has been confirmed to work with "-ReadOnly" parameter).

There are two MS KB articles about hotfixes that introduce "Application Intent", but they are for Framework versions [3.5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2654347/en-us) and [4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2544514/en-us). <strike>I am not finding anything for 4.5, so I assume support is included</strike>. Both [4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205662%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [SQL Server Native Client](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471494.aspx) should support it out-of-the-box.

We are using 4.5.

This is the connection string:

```
Data Source=HAListener;Initial Catalog=*********;User ID=************;Password=********; Application Intent=ReadOnly
```

Anybody encountered this error?

**SOLVED**
There shouldn't be any space in Application Intent:

```
ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly
```

Comment: NOt Sure But i have use before is (Info=False;Mode=Read) Rather than (Application Intent=ReadOnly) give it a try if that's help...:)

Comment: You need to make sure you have all updates installed. That connection string attribute isn't understood by the RTM versions of some of the components you are using.

Comment: @Ikiet, it errors, but even if it worked, it probably wouldn't have triggered the behavior we're aiming at on the HA listener - namely to "load balance" the connection to a readable replica, different than the primary. FYI, the error is `ERROR: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'info'.`

Comment: First, show us your actual code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess I'll post the solution in case someone else encounters the same issue:

there is no space between Application and Intent. the correct parameter is:

```
ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly
```

(reference: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the SNAC protocol you are using there is a slight variation in the application intent connection string property.

When using SQL Native Access Client SQL OLE DB, the application intent connection string should be specified with a space: 'Application Intent'

When connecting using SQLClient or ODBC specify 'ApplicationIntent' with no space